# Mac Zlib ndefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

Tags: c++, c, macos, zlib

I am trying to build a simple program using zlib.h in Xcode to read in and inflate .gz file. Though when building the program I am getting the infamous

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:

 "_inflate", referenced from:
      decomp() in main.o
  "_inflateEnd", referenced from:
      decomp() in main.o
  "_inflateInit2_", referenced from:
      decomp() in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

For the zlib methods inflate, inflateEnd etc.

```
#include <zlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
...inflate method here..}
```

Thanks
Sam

Comment: You have to link with the zlib library as well.

Comment: add LIBS += -lz during compilation

Comment: added linker flag -lz , working, thanks!

Comment: I had the same issue. Any reason/explanation why you need to use `-lz`. I see it referenced in multiple places but now one gives a reason why. Thank you!

Comment: `-l` is a compiler option for including a library during the linker phase when producing a binary. `-lz` means link with the library `z`. So the compiler will look for a file named `"lib"+"z"` followed by the file extensions corresponding to a library: e.g. `libz.a`, `libz.dylib`, `libz.so`, `libz.dll`